# Reemplazar una ruta por un código hash en Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, hash

Llevo semanas tratando de implementar una función en Laravel 5.7 pero no he podido.
La idea es esta: por ejemplo, tengo esta ruta: https://midominio.com/menu-del-usuario y lo que quiero es cambiarlo por algo como: https://midominio.com/fdsjfhdsfkjsas siendo esto un código generado internamente. ¿Tienen alguna idea de cómo hacerlo por favor? Los artículos que he revisado solo cifran los IDs, no he podido encontrar algún artículo donde ocultan la ruta completa. Espero haberme explicado lo suficientemente claro.
Gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: Disculpa mi curiosidad pero, ¿por qué quieres hacer algo como eso?

Comment: Es para evitar que adivinen las rutas, es un sistema multi-usuario donde cada usuario tiene su propio menú. He notado que al cambiar cualquier palabra por otra si existe me dirige a la ruta y quiero evitar eso. Ya lo solucioné, no hay un método de hasheo, tuve que cifrar las rutas yo mismo.